# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.NoMatchingPrincipalException: An error occurred while enumerating the groups. The group could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory

I want to get the Groups of a User from the Active Directory by an User Principal. For this task, I wrote the following static function:

```
internal static List<ADGroup> GetGroupsByIdentity(UserPrincipal pUserPrincipal)
{
    var lResult = new List<ADGroup>();

    if (pUserPrincipal != null)
    {
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> lGroups = pUserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();

        // iterate over all groups
        foreach (Principal p in lGroups)
        {
            // make sure to add only group principals
            if (p is GroupPrincipal)
            {
                var lGroupName = "";
                var lGroupSid = "";

                try
                {
                    lGroupName = p.Name;
                    lGroupSid = p.Sid.Value;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lGroupName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lGroupSid) &&
                        !lResult.Any(x => x.Sid == lGroupSid))
                    {
                        lResult.Add(new ADGroup(p));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (e is PrincipalOperationException || e is NoMatchingPrincipalException)
                    {
                        // perhaps the SID could not be resolved
                        // perhaps the SID does not exist in the AD any more
                        // ignore and proceed with next

                        p.Dispose();
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }                           
                }
                finally
                {
                    p.Dispose();
                }
            }

            p.Dispose();
        }
    }

    return lResult;
}
```

When the user executes this code, he gets an Exception. Here is a part of the stack:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.NoMatchingPrincipalException: 
An error occurred while enumerating the groups. The group could not be found. 
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet.get_CurrentAsPrincipal() 
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.get_Current() 
at xxx.xxxxxxxxx.Mvc.CustomSetup.ADHandler.GetGroupsByIdentity(UserPrincipal pUserPrincipal) // the function above
at ...
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like the method GetAuthorizationGroups() have a few limitations. This is an old Exception that have existed since 2009. And Microsoft won't fix it because "there is a reasonable workaround". https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522539/clr-forum-error-calling-principal-getauthorizationgroups-in-winxp-sp3

I got this error when using Principal.IsMemberOf(). I searched if a user existed in a custom list of groups. If a group didn't exist in the Domain, it threw this

```
System.DirectryServices.AccountManagement.NoMatchingPrincipalException
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.nomatchingprincipalexception(v=vs.110).aspx

**Error example 1 using .IsMemberOf()**

```
List<string> groups = Constants.ADGroups(); // List of AD groups to test against               

var context = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Domain,
    "Domain");

var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
    context,
    IdentityType.SamAccountName,
    httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

// Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)
foreach (var group in groups)
    if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group))
        return true;
```

**Error example 2 using .GetAuthorizationGroups():**

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"Domain");

var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                                   context,
                                   IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                   httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

if (userPrincipal != null)
{
    var principalGroups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();
    foreach (var principalGroup in principalGroups)
    {
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            if (String.Equals(
                principalGroup.Name,
                group,
                StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 1: Proposed workaround is to iterate over AD Groups:**

[GetAuthorizationGroups() is throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221974/getauthorizationgroups-is-throwing-exception?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
var iterGroup = groups.GetEnumerator();
using (iterGroup)
{
    while (iterGroup.MoveNext())
    {
        try
        {
            Principal p = iterGroup.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
        catch (NoMatchingPrincipalException pex)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: What I instead ended up using (MVC app using Windows Authentication):**

This is a lighter way to check auth, iterating over a large company's AD can be slow...

```
var wi = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
if (wi != null)
{
    var wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wi);
    List<string> groups = Constants.ADGroups(); // List of AD groups to test against

    foreach (var @group in groups)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Searching for {@group}");
        if (wp.IsInRole(@group))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The connect.microsoft.com link at the beginning of this answer is available on archive.org. https://web.archive.org/web/20111228120641/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522539/clr-forum-error-calling-principal-getauthorizationgroups-in-winxp-sp3